# Android Eclipse emulator problem: Runs WVGA(hdpi) as a mdpi screen

Tags: android, eclipse, emulation

The problem I am having is that when I run a FWVGA or WVGA sized emulator it sometimes runs at a MDPI size instead of HDPI. Here is an example with pictures

http://wonton-games.blogspot.com/2010/06/emulator-problems.html

I create the AVD with the proper hw.lcd.density setting and screen size and it randomly does this. There doesn't seem to be a pattern. I used to be able to just delete the AVD and create it over again and it would fix itself for a while but now it's getting worse.

Does anyone have any ideas cause I posted on the Android Developer forum but all I got was other people saying they get the same problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I get the same problem and find that it is often only solved by a reboot - of my PC rather than of the emulator.  I've not needed to edit or recreate the AVD to solve the problem.

I *think* it might be related to unplugging my laptop from an external monitor and so changes the Windows display resolution but I haven't been able to regularly recreate the problem.

Since the same AVD image can work one day and not the next and the start working again after a reboot means that this must be a bug in the emulator rather than a problem with the configuration of the AVD.

Unfortunately, I don't know of any workarounds for the problem and as far as I can tell this [hasn't been logged as a bug](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/list).  (I haven't logged it myself since, as you say, it occurs randomly which makes it hard to fill in a decent bug report.)

Comment: +1 random. :-( I find that the error occurs more often with the "Google API" images than on the vanilla Android images, but since it happens at random, I could be mistaken.

Comment: +1 seems like plugging in an external monitor makes the problem more likely on my OSX 10.6 machine.