# Why does Motorola Atrix load mdpi-drawables?

Tags: android

I created an AVD.

resolution: 540 x 960
hw.lcd.density: 275

Before starting the AVD I scaled the emulator to 4". So the AVD is similiar to the Atrix.

But why does it load mdpi drawable? I put a Bitmap in these folders:

drawble-ldpi
drawble-mdpi
drawble-hdpi

The Bitmap contains only a small Text, which says "ldpi", "mdpi", or "hdpi".

My manifest contains:

```
<supports-screens android:resizeable="true" />
<supports-screens android:smallScreens="true" />
<supports-screens android:normalScreens="true" />
<supports-screens android:largeScreens="true" />
<supports-screens android:xlargeScreens="true" />
<supports-screens android:anyDensity="true" />
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Maybe the fact that you can plug it in to a tablet-like display has something to do with it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems someone else had a similar issue, but managed to resolve it:

[Android Eclipse emulator problem: Runs WVGA(hdpi) as a mdpi screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3305941/android-eclipse-emulator-problem-runs-wvgahdpi-as-a-mdpi-screen)